# Write wchar_t* to file - works only for some characters

Tags: c++, wchar-t

I have methods which returns unicode texts and i need to write them into file but some characters are not written. I have the following:

```
const wchar_t* getStandardText() {
    return L"test";
}

const wchar_t* getUnicodeText()
{
    return L"testíček";
}

int main()
{
    FILE *file = fopen(FILE_NAME, "a");

    fputws(getStandardText(), file);
    fputws(getUnicodeText(), file);

    fclose(file);
}
```

Output in file:

> testtestí

Much more confusing for me is that some characters like "í" works and others like "č" not.

- I am on Windows with VS 2015 Pro.
- For reading of file i use Notepad++ which tells me the file has ANSI encoding.

Comment: Your function `getASCII` have quite a misleading name. Also, on what system are you running this program on? And how do you check the contents of the file?

Comment: What encoding is your source code in and how are you compiling it?

Comment: A file is a sequence of **bytes**. How those bytes are interpretted as characters can vary. So unless you can say how you are checking the output of your file, it's impossible to answer your question. Questions about international characters are very difficult because most newbies don't know how to ask the right question. They just expect characters to work but it's not as simple as that.

Comment: I have added more information into question, thanks.

Comment: You maybe need ccs settings. See Microsoft docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen

Comment: "ANSI" is not an encoding. (I know Windows likes to claim otherwise, but it's wrong.)

Comment: _"...which tells me the file has ANSI encoding..."_ Unless the file has a BOM, Notepad has to guess the encoding using a combination of heuristics; this is error prone.  Inspect the file in a hex editor to see the actual bytes written.

Comment: "í" is part of ASCII, while "č" is not. That probably explains why it works. http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: @RichardCritten Notepad++ is not Notepad. Notepad++ does a smarter check on the file content (but not infallible of course)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works on Windows... Change your `mode` parameter to have an explicit encoding...

```
FILE *file = fopen("foobar.txt", "a+, ccs=UTF-16LE");
```

OR

```
FILE *file = fopen("foobar.txt", "a+, ccs=UTF-8");
```

That appears to force the byte-order-marks (`FF FE`) onto the file header to indicate the file's text is Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

The file has to be created with appropriate BOM. Following is the most preferred way, and make sure you're dumping only UTF-8 characters to the file. And open through notepad++ to view it.

```
FILE *file = fopen("test.txt", "a+, ccs=UTF-8");
```